# Algorithms: Find recursive equation of divide and conquer algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, runtime, divide-and-conquer

I have the following "divide and conquer" algorithm A1.

A1 divides a problem with *size* **n** , to 4 sub-problems with *size* **n/4**.
Then, *solves them and compose* the solutions to **12n time**.

How can I to write the recursive equation that give the runtime of algorithms.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem

Comment: OK, and where are you stuck?

Comment: @PaulHankin I edited my question

Answer (score 1):

Answering the question "How can I to write the recursive equation that give the runtime of algorithms"

You should write it this way:
Let T(n) denote the run time of your algorithm for input size of n

T(n)  = 4*T(n/4) + 12*n;

Answer (score 1):

Although the master theorem does give a shortcut to the answer, it is imperative to understand the derivation of the Big O runtime. Divide and conquer recurrence relations are written in the form `T(n) = q * T(n/j) + cn`, where `q` is the number of subproblems, `j` the amount we divide the data for each subproblem, and `cn` is the time it takes to divide/combine/manipulate each subproblem at each level. `cn` could also be `cn^2` or `c`, whatever the runtime would be.

In your case, you have 4 subproblems of size n/4 with each level being solved in `12n` time giving a recurrence relation of `T(n) = 4 * T(n/4) + 12n`. From this recurrence, we can then derive the runtime of the algorithm. Given it is a divide and conquer relation, we can assume that the base case is `T(1) = 1`.

To solve the recurrence, I will use a technique called substitution. We know that `T(n) = 4 * T(n/4) + 12n`, so we will substitute for `T(n/4). T(n/4) = 4 * T(n/16) + 12(n/4)`. Plugging this into the equation gets us `T(n) = 4 * (4 * T(n/16) + 12n/4) + 12n`, which we can simplify to `T(n) = 4^2 * T(n/16) + 2* 12n`.  Again, we still have more work to do in the equation to capture the work in all levels, so we substitute for `T(n/16), T(n) = 4^3 * T(n/64) +  3* 12n`. We see the pattern emerge and know that we want to go all the way down to our base case, `T(1)`, so that we substitute to get `T(n) = 4^k*T(1) + k * 12n`. This equation defines the total amount of work that is in the divide and conquer algorithm because we have substituted all of the levels in, however, we still have an unknown variable k and we want it in terms of `n` We get `k` by solving the equation `n/4^k = 1` as we know that we have reached the point where we are calling the algorithm on only one variable. We solve for n and get that `k = log4n`. That means that we have done `log4n` substitutions. We plug that in for `k` and get `T(n) =4^log4n*T(1) + log4n * 12n`. We simplify this to `T(n) =n *1 + log4n * 12n`. Since this is Big O analysis and `log4n` is in `O(log2n)` due to the change of base property of logarithms, we get that `T(n) = n + 12n * logn` which means that `T(n)` is in the Big O of `nlogn`.

Answer (score 0):

Recurrence relation that best describes is given by:

```
T(n)=4*T(n/4)+12*n
```

Where `T(n)`= run time of given algorithm for input of size n, `4`= no of subproblems,`n/4` = size of each subproblem .

Using Master Theorem Time Complexity is calculated to be:`theta(n*log n)`